# Does the E2-Micro come under the GCE Free Tier?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I had a `F1-micro` instance created that was part of the [Compute Engine Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute). A month ago i received an email stating

> ...
> We’ve identified that you’re using an F1-micro instance that is a part
> of the Compute Engine Free Tier. As we improve the experience of the
> Free Tier, we will be introducing the E2-micro VM, which is a part of
> a second generation VM family. It offers additional resources for your
> use, specifically 0.25 vCPU (which burst to 2 vCPU periodically) and 1
> GB of RAM.
>
> What do I need to know? The Free Tier F1-micro VM is changing to the
> E2-micro VM as the VM to use for free. On August 1, 2021, E2-micro
> Free Tier will be introduced. Follow these steps to change your
> machine type to E2-micro to avoid incurring charges for continuing to
> use F1-micro after August 31, 2021.
>
> What do I need to do? Starting August 1, 2021, change the machine type
> from F1-micro, or stop your existing F1-micro instance and begin using
> a E2-micro instance. VMs created with either method will automatically
> have the Free Tier discount applied to them. The supported regions
> will remain the same.
> ...

So i went ahead and changed it to an `E2-micro` and all went well.

Today i have a need to create a brand new instance so i removed the existing E2 instance(which was created mostly to test waters so to speak) and started the process to (re)create an `E2-Micro` instance from scratch.

I chose the correct options for region/zone and when i chose the `E2-micro` option i find that the discount isn't applied.

[image]

When i choose a `F1-micro` i see the discount applied. See the text 'Your first 720 hours....' (which apparently needs to exist for the discounts to be applied per this (rather outdated) [article](https://hbmy289.medium.com/how-to-set-up-a-free-micro-vps-on-google-cloud-platform-bddee893ac09)).

[image]

Is this just a case of the documentation not reflecting the actual facts as yet? Can i go ahead and continue creating the `E2-micro` despite not seeing the information regarding the free-tier appliecation applied?

Note: I did send an email with my queries to the official ID but haven't got a response yet. So as suggested on the support pages I am using one of the supported community-support options, Stackoverflow.

Comment: You _may_ want to try to submit a ticket in the Google IssueTracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues); it may not lead to a direct answer, but it will give your question _somewhat_ more exposure.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the link. The issue tracker route didn't cross my mind at all. IMO thats a drastic step for what i gather is a simple query. But yes, you are right. There is a better possibility of getting qualified answers. I will do that.

Comment: The other option i had - and which i might have continued with - is to simply go by the documentation  that exists on the day i create the instance. The email doesn't specify anything wrt new instances so i guess the documentation will override it.

Comment: The IssueTracker hasn't helped me in the past, but I thought I would suggest it just in case.  Should've just suggested you contact GCP Billing: expensive enterprise-level support aside, billing used to be the only way I was able to contact GCP support myself years ago.  I know you're just making use of Compute's Free Tier for now, but that couldn't hurt either.

Comment: Wish I could help you more, but GCP is opaque and closed-source; there is no way to know for sure.  Working with GCP for a little while, I have noticed some inconsistencies even in official documentation.  Even though it gets a small share of the IaaS market, it is still too large to have completely consistent documentation.  Looking forward to you getting an answer.

Comment: I absolutely understand about the documentation. The scale is mind-boggling considering the vast range of products as well as  the constant changes and innovations. Unfortunately though it is also the single source of truth for most end users out there, or at least for non-enterprise users. $29 pm, though somewhat steep, is ok if the end solution generates revenue somehow, which it doesn't atm. And so I am trying every which way to stay within the free tiers :). All said, I have to admit that the GCP free tiers are generally quite generous across their offerings.

Comment: You use **balanced persistent disk** which is must be **paid**. To use free tier use **standard persistent disk**.

Comment: "Your first 744 hours of e2-micro instance usage are free this month" text is not showing anymore, which is frustrating. But folks say that you will not be charged for free tier machines started. Please take a look at this ticket https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/GCP-free-tier-problem/m-p/395149/highlight/true#M447

Answer (score 16):

The machine type e2-micro is part of the free tier, when creating the instance it shows an estimated cost just to show how much it would cost, this doesn't mean you will be charged. The discount is applied once the VM instance is running and it will be reflected on the billing reports.

The billing reports get updated daily, but if you would like to know your monthly estimate you can see it in the section where it shows you the $7.12 charge, you just need to remove the instance cost.

Your Free Tier e2-micro instance limit is by time, not by instance. Each month, eligible use of all of your e2-micro instances is free until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month. Usage calculations are combined across the supported [regions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones).

[Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute) free tier does not charge for an external IP address.
GPUs and TPUs are not included in the Free Tier offer. You are always charged for GPUs and TPUs that you add to VM instances.

Refer [compute engine pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing) for more information.

I would recommend you to contact the [Sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact) if you have any further billing related questions.

Comment: _"The machine type e2-micro is part of the free tier... Each month, eligible use of all of your e2-micro instances is free until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month."_  Is it still true? Does this free tier e2-micro machine still gets month credits? I found that my free tier e2-micro machine is not accessible any more now, which is now insisting that _"Billing must be enabled for activation of service"_.